# How to recover a particular database from MySQL dump file?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I was having a website at a hosting while taking the backup I took the backup of whole mysql by mistake which includes databases of all my other websites also.

So now the problem is I want to extract that particular database from complete sql file?
Is there any procedure to do it or can we import that complete dump file into a mysql. So that later I can export that particular database after importing it to MySQL.

Please help me or suggest me how to do it.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

http://fragments.turtlemeat.com/mysql-database-backup-restore-phpmyadmin.php

This should help.

Answer (score 0):

If the size of the schemas in your backup file that you do **not** want to restore are not that big and there aren't that many other schemas in there, your best bet would probably be to just restore the entire backup and then do a backup of just your schema. One easy way to backup just your schema is to use [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/). If you run into problems getting setup or doing the backup you might want to check [this little write up](http://forum.hostek.com/showthread.php?297-How-to-use-MySQL-Workbench-to-backup-your-MySQL-database) that walks you through installation and performing a backup.